# Big-O Question 1

Tags: discrete-mathematics

We have to find the least integer such that $f(x)$ is $O(x^n)$ for the given function. 
We also have to find the smallest corresponding witnesses $C$ and $K$. 
Here is what I have, let me know where I am going wrong:

$f(x)$= $5x^4$ + $4x$ + $1$

$|f(x)|$ = |$5x^4$ + $4x$ + $1$|

$\le$ $5x^4$ +$4x$ + $1$ for all $x$ $\gt$ $0$

$\le$ $5x^4$ + $4x^4$ $1x^4$ for all $x$ $\gt$ $1$

$\le$ $10x^4$ for all $x$ for all $x$ $\gt$ $1$

We conclude that $f(x)$ is $O(x^4)$ for $C = 10$ and $K = 1$ from the definition of Big-O.

Have i missed a step?

Comment: It is suggestive to point out the domain of any function. Also, some notations, like $C$ and $K$ shouldn't appear suddenly as they were not mentioned in your problem.

Comment: @Zhanxiong i added the C and K, can you please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

Your proof that $f(x)=O(x^4)$ is correct. Now, you need to prove it's it not $ O(x^c)$ for any $c < 4$.

A possibly simpler way is to use the following characterization:

> $f(x)=O(x^n)$ (at $\infty$) if, and only if, $\limsup_{x\to\infty}\frac{\lvert f(x)\rvert }{x^n} < \infty$

(in many cases, it suffices to show that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\lvert f(x)\rvert }{x^n} = c < \infty$ for some $c$. In particular, here you get $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\lvert f(x)\rvert }{x^4} = 5$, but $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\lvert f(x)\rvert }{x^3} = \infty$.

The following will not give you the constants $C$ and $K$ directly (although you gives you that any $C>c$ would work, for some suitable $K$; and that any $C<c$ cannot work) -- but allows to prove and eyeball the correct answer very easily.

Answer (score 0):

It would be advised to say $|f(x)| = |5x^4 + 4x + 1| = 5x^4 + 4 + 1$ at the beginning there instead of $\leq$ since it is only ever $=$. Other than that, your proof that $f(x) = O(x^4)$ is correct, but you also must now prove that $f(x)$ is not $O(x^3)$.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring out this answer and it follows below

---

Claim $f(x)= 0(x^4)$ and $n=4$ is the smallest integer so that $f(x)=0(x^n)$

Let $n > 4 $

$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x^n } = \lim_{x \to \infty} 5x^{4-n} + 4x^{1-n}+ \frac{1}{n} = 0 + 0 + 0 $

since $4-n<0, 1-n < 0$

Let $n=4$

$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x^4 } = \lim_{x \to \infty} 5+ \frac{4}{x^3}+ \frac{1}{x^4}= 5$

Let C be any number greater than 5

$C= 5.1$

We now want to find k so that for $x \geqslant k$ :
$\frac{f(x)}{x^4}= 5+ \frac{4}{x^3} + \frac{1}{x^4} \leqslant 5.1 $

Choose $k=4$ is $x$ $\geqslant$ $k$

Then $\frac{4}{x^3} \leqslant \frac{4}{4^3}= \frac {1}{16} $

$\frac {1}{x^4} \leqslant$ $\frac {4}{4^4} = \frac {1}{64}$

Since $\frac {1}{16} + \frac{1}{64} \leqslant *1$  shown that

if $x \geqslant 4 \frac {f(x)}{x^4} \leqslant 5 + 1$

So $f(x) \geqslant 5*1 x^4$